# How do I check missing values from a table which represents multiple hourly time series (DB2)?

Tags: sql, database, timestamp, db2

Imagine I have a DB2 table called FOO with a time series id, a timestamp value every hour and an integer number. This is the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO(
    Id_timeseries      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    number              DECIMAL(10, 3) NOT NULL,
    timestamp          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
);
```

I would like to know, for each time series (imagine that there are several of them) if there are empty values between two given dates and what are those empty dates(I suppose that giving the range of those values would be a lot more difficult)

Example:

```
Id_timeseries    number     timestamp
1                 28        2017-01-01 01:00:00
1                 28        2017-01-01 02:00:00
1                 28        2017-01-01 03:00:00
2                 28        2017-01-01 01:00:00
2                 28        2017-01-01 02:00:00
2                 28        2017-01-01 03:00:00
1                 28        2017-01-01 07:00:00
1                 28        2017-01-01 06:00:00
```

And I want to know the missing houly values from `2017:01-01 00:00:00` to `2017:01-02 00:00:00`

Output:

```
Id_timeseries    from                   to
1                2017:01-01 00:00:00    2017:01-01 00:00:00
1                2017:01-01 04:00:00    2017:01-01 05:00:00
1                2017:01-01 08:00:00    2017:01-01 23:00:00
2                2017:01-01 00:00:00    2017:01-01 00:00:00
2                2017:01-01 04:00:00    2017:01-01 23:00:00
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the advice. There you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH FOO (Id_timeseries, number, timestamp) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 01:00:00'))
, (1, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 02:00:00'))
, (1, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 03:00:00'))
, (1, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 06:00:00'))
, (1, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 07:00:00'))
--, (1, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00'))
--, (1, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 23:00:00'))
--, (1, 28, timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00'))
, (2, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 01:00:00'))
, (2, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 02:00:00'))
, (2, 28, timestamp('2017-01-01 03:00:00'))
)
-- Internal gaps
SELECT Id_timeseries, timestamp_prev + 1 hour as from, timestamp - 1 hour as to
FROM
(
SELECT Id_timeseries, timestamp, lag(timestamp) over (partition by Id_timeseries order by timestamp) timestamp_prev
FROM FOO
)
WHERE timestamp_prev <> timestamp - 1 hour
-- Start gap
  UNION ALL
SELECT Id_timeseries, timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00') as from, min(timestamp) - 1 hour as to
FROM FOO
GROUP BY Id_timeseries
HAVING timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00') <> min(timestamp)
-- End gap
  UNION ALL
SELECT Id_timeseries, max(timestamp) + 1 hour as from, timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00') as to 
FROM FOO
GROUP BY Id_timeseries
HAVING timestamp('2017-01-02 00:00:00') <> max(timestamp)
ORDER BY Id_timeseries, from;
```

The result is:

```
|ID_TIMESERIES|FROM                      |TO                        |
|-------------|--------------------------|--------------------------|
|1            |2017-01-01-00.00.00.000000|2017-01-01-00.00.00.000000|
|1            |2017-01-01-04.00.00.000000|2017-01-01-05.00.00.000000|
|1            |2017-01-01-08.00.00.000000|2017-01-02-00.00.00.000000|
|2            |2017-01-01-00.00.00.000000|2017-01-01-00.00.00.000000|
|2            |2017-01-01-04.00.00.000000|2017-01-02-00.00.00.000000|
```